# It is possible save node_models on gitlab ci runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have `gitlab ci runner` on my machine. I am interesting or exist way save `node_modules` on worker and update it when `yarn.lock` changes? Probably it will save time to install modules every time?